# Stripe Payment not going through with Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, stripe-payments

I'm trying to test a payment gateway method with stripe and I have this error when i try to click the button which it said "[log] {success: false, error: o is not defined}", here is my code. I'm not sure what or how to solve this but I would really need some help on this one. Also I included with the screenshot of the problem

```
Main.dart

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
Future <void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: FirebaseOptions(apiKey: "AIzaSyD7Uhhiv85NCcDjoTEQ-K7T5qU4bNXci8M",
        appId: "XXX", messagingSenderId: "XXX",
        projectId: "itt632-56973",



      ));
  Stripe.publishableKey = "pk_test_51LHIjvJ5bt4B4CmJ3xTspeufDqv4VojZlmhuBaVvjhUoDbJaoKziiUkFZPOTl3a4CbVcfdmnJKosItZiiweRYfvF00aOI2xKIS";
  Stripe.instance.applySettings();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Demo(),
    );
  }
}


// 'https://us-central1-itt632-56973.cloudfunctions.net/stripePaymentIntentRequest'),

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  const Demo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  Future<void> initPayment(
      {required String email,
        required double amount,
        required BuildContext context}) async {
    try {
      // 1. Create a payment intent on the server
      final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(
              'https://us-central1-itt632-56973.cloudfunctions.net/stripePaymentIntentRequest'),
          body: {
            'email': email,
            'amount': amount.toString(),
          });

      final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      log(jsonResponse.toString());
      // 2. Initialize the payment sheet
      await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
            paymentIntentClientSecret: jsonResponse['paymentIntent'],
            merchantDisplayName: 'Grocery Flutter course',
            customerId: jsonResponse['customer'],
            customerEphemeralKeySecret: jsonResponse['ephemeralKey'],
            testEnv: true,
            merchantCountryCode: 'SG',
          ));
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Payment is successful'),
        ),
      );
    } catch (errorr) {
      if (errorr is StripeException) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('An error occured ${errorr.error.localizedMessage}'),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('An error occured $errorr'),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Pay 50\$'),
            onPressed: () async {
              await initPayment(
                  amount: 50.0, context: context, email: 'JEFRILUQMAN@test.com');
            },
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the index.js function for the stripe

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_51LHIjvJ5bt4B4CmJclvzNcSaSPICuutFIjmg3GZb1sv6fySDehLAhvHOW2hl1W7EWXYM5oqfHkHZyJDeB36rIJpf00ksfQJnWa");
exports.stripePaymentIntentRequest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let customerId;

        //Gets the customer who's email id matches the one sent by the client
        const customerList = await stripe.customers.list({
            email: req.body.email,
            limit: 1
        });

        //Checks the if the customer exists, if not creates a new customer
        if (customerList.data.length !== 0) {
            customerId = customerList.data[0].id;
        }
        else {
            const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                email: req.body.email
            });
            customerId = customer.data.id;
        }

        //Creates a temporary secret key linked with the customer
        const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
            { customer: customerId },
            { apiVersion: '2020-08-27' }
        );

        //Creates a new payment intent with amount passed in from the client
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: parseInt(req.body.amount),
            currency: 'usd',
            customer: customerId,
        })

        res.status(200).send({
            paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
            ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
            customer: customerId,
            success: true,
        })

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send({ success: false, error: error.message })
    }
});
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTb4A.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2S9K.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding log statements to pinpoint exactly where the error is occurring?

Comment: I already did and it shows like this " [log] {success: false, error: o is not defined}" . Its not making any sense

Comment: No I mean add more log statements. Like a log statement before each line so that you know the exact line of code that's causing the problem.

Comment: the problem seems to caused in this line log(jsonResponse.toString()); . Im not sure what exactly need to be added before each line. If possible, can you just show me a way on how to add each log statement?

Comment: Whenever i change my dummy email. The log will return this error [log] {success: false, error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')}. Seems like whenever i change to a new dummy email it shows undefined, not sure how to solve this problem